# Options for a D&D 3.5 Play-By-Email Game

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I would like to get involved in a Play-By-Email game, as a character not DM. Where is the best place to begin my search for such a game?

Comment: Related and may duplicate: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2877/how-can-i-find-pbp-games

Comment: this is not a duplicate .. i am looking for pbem games, which is different to pbp.

Comment: many use `pbp` / `play-by-post` to include games played by email, forum, phpBB, etc. See the [`play-by-post`](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/play-by-post) tag description, which is why I had added that tag.

Answer (score 2):

mxyzplk's link is good, here are a couple of others I haven't seen yet (I'll add these to the wiki later too):
[MyRPG](http://myrpg.universeprojects.com/) is growing and has some pretty advanced tools.
[Ongoing worlds](http://www.ongoingworlds.com/) is another good site.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would have to be the worst way to play D&D 3.5. But I guess many people do play this way. You might find this site to be useful.

http://www.dndonlinegames.com/